# Twitter Bootstrap Drop Down on Hover of Active Removes Background

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a drop down menu and it works fine until I hover over the the active page, it removes the background. Thanks for any help, and if you need anything else or need me to clarify anything please ask.

Dropdown and Nav CSS

```
.navbar-custom {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.3);
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: Montserrat,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    background-color: #000;
}

.navbar-custom .navbar-brand {
    font-weight: 700;
}

.navbar-custom .navbar-brand:focus {
    outline: 0;
}

.navbar-custom .navbar-brand .navbar-toggle {
    padding: 4px 6px;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #fff;
}

.navbar-custom .navbar-brand .navbar-toggle:focus,
.navbar-custom .navbar-brand .navbar-toggle:active {
    outline: 0;
}

.navbar-custom a {
    color: #fff;
}

.navbar-custom .nav li.active {
    outline: none;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.3);
}

.navbar-custom .nav li a {
    -webkit-transition: background .3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: background .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: background .3s ease-in-out;
}

.navbar-custom .nav li a:hover,
.navbar-custom .nav li a:focus {
    outline: 0;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.3);
}

@media(min-width:767px) {
    .navbar {
        padding: 20px 0;
        border-bottom: 0;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
        background: 0 0;
        -webkit-transition: background .5s ease-in-out,padding .5s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: background .5s ease-in-out,padding .5s ease-in-out;
        transition: background .5s ease-in-out,padding .5s ease-in-out;
    }

    .top-nav-collapse {
        padding: 0;
        background-color: #000;
    }

    .navbar-custom.top-nav-collapse {
        border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.3);
    }
}

.dropdown-menu>.active>a,
.dropdown-menu>.active>a:hover,
.dropdown-menu>.active>a:focus,
.dropdown-menu>.active>a:active {
    background-color: #A8A8A8; 
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0jh1ffa6/) but it doesnt look right because of lack of bootstrap.

Also if you want to download the files and view them that way i have them in a dropbox [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/eok8zv7a5xqdu3s/AAAM073765SnQw7rSsYWTqD9a?dl=0).

Comment: Try to set up a live example on the jsfiddle.net with a piece of the code.

Comment: I added Bootstrap CSS and JS to the Fiddle. I also added your CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/0jh1ffa6/2/

Comment: Thanks, any other answers?

Answer (score 0):

**Updated again:** (I have suddenly got right to edit other people's answers. Found that out the hard way by editing the wrong answer ...)

The problem is, as far as I can see, related to main.css on line 100:

```
.navbar-custom .nav li a:hover,
.navbar-custom .nav li a:focus {
    outline: 0;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.3);
}
```

try to add:

```
.navbar-custom .nav li.active a:hover {
background-color: #8E8E8E; /*add whatever color you'd like on background on hover*/
}
```

Updated answer:
Is this what you want? (That the "Assignments" is semi-transparent and not a full light grey background)

[image]

Then add this to your CSS:

```
a.dropdown-toggle {
background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.3) !important;
}
```

OLD answer:

It is much easier to find if you'd share a link to the site, as custom CSS can effect this a lot.

This has a background that is nearly invisible. You may see it as transparent, depends on you other backgrounds below the menu.

```
   .navbar-custom .nav li a:hover,
    .navbar-custom .nav li a:focus {
        outline: 0;
        background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.3);
    }
```

The color: rgba(255,255,255,.3) means RED GREEN BLUE, where all colors are at full. The .3 means that the color har opacity (is transparent). Opacity 0 = full transparent. Opacity 1.0 = not transparent

Comment: this doesn't affect the dropdown just the basic nav

Comment: Normally yes. That is why I'd like to see his full site. That is the only thing I can see in the provided CSS that could have the effect he is mentioning.

Comment: I added the files in form of dropbox, sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Check the above image. Is this what you want?

Comment: I can't view the image, but the hover on the non active drop down works fine it is just when it is active that it removes the background hence making it so you can't see the letters. On the drop down it should not do anything except change the cursor on the hover over the active page.

Comment: So this is only efected when the active page is one of the pages in the drop down, for example the weight training page, and you hover over the active page. Here is picture from before http://i61.tinypic.com/25rfevk.jpg and here is picture from hover http://i58.tinypic.com/2ufvls8.jpg

Comment: I don't think this is fixable for whatever reason, because I can change it so the color changes on hover but the background always changes to white. I have checked bootstrap and there is nothing that changes the background color to white so I really don't know. Thanks for all the help and if someone figures this out, you are amazing!

Answer (score 0):

The selector that corresponds to the html-markup should be`.dropdown-menu .active li a:hover`

try adding to CSS

```
.dropdown-menu .active li a:hover{
background-color: #A8A8A8; 
color: #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: this doesnt affect the dropdown just the basic nav